# if answer == "M": print(mult(a, b))

Tags: python

I have to make two recursive functions that divide and multiply in Python and I don't know what is wrong with the following code:

```
def mult(a, b):
   if a == 0:
      return 0
   elif a == 1:
      return b
   else:
      return mult(a-1, b) + b

def div(a, b):
    if (a >= b):
        return div(a - b, b) + 1
    else: return 0

def main():

    a = input("Please enter your first value.\n")
    b = input("Please enter your second value.\n")

    answer = input("Please enter M or D. M to multiply your 2 values or D for Divide.\n")

    if answer == "M":
        print(mult(a, b))
    elif answer == "D":
        print(div(a, b))

main()
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python 3, both `a` and `b` are strings.  If you want to convert them to integers, you can do:

```
a = int(input("Please enter your first value.\n"))
b = int(input("Please enter your second value.\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are using Python 3.

The `input()` function in Python 3 will always return a string so then `a` and `b` will be strings in your code rather than integers. You must type case them explicitly to integers using

`a = int(a)` and `b = int(b)`

Answer (score 0):

You could have provided the error, or even better, googled the error. I ran your code and the problem is that your input is a string, but you're trying to use it as an integer.

These lines:

```
a = input("Please enter your first value.\n")
b = input("Please enter your second value.\n")
```

Should have been:

```
a = int(input("Please enter your first value.\n"))
b = int(input("Please enter your second value.\n"))
```

Also your code could check for lowercase "M" and "D", you can do that by adding .upper() at the end of your input line.

```
answer = input("Please enter M or D. M to multiply your 2 values or D for Divide.\n").upper()
```